# Example of primitive function which isn't Riemann-integrable on a closed interval [0,1]

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

Can you give me an example of a bounded f:[0,1]-> R , which has a primitive but it isn't Riemann-integrable? It must be on a closed interval from zero to one.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Suositeltua lukemistoa [kysymisestä yleensä](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) ja [MathJaxin käytöstä](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/11619) (LaTeXin mark-up versio)

Comment: Can you give a definition of *has a primitive*, please? I thought that a primitive of $f$ is a differentiable function $F$ with derivative $F'=f$. Is the idea that we only require that almost everywhere? Or what? Sorry about being rusty here, this may be a standard definition :-)

Comment: Can you provide some contexts? Depending on the restriction (such as boundedness on the derivative) a [**counter example**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function) can be quite involved.

Comment: Hey, 
In calculus, an antiderivative, primitive function, primitive integral or indefinite integral  of a function f is a differentiable function F whose derivative is equal to the original function f. This can be stated symbolically as F ′ = f.

Comment: I have tried x^2sin(1/x) and 1/x. It must be bounded in the closed interval [0,1]

Comment: It has to have a primitive but no Riemann-integrable. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Thanks for help guys

Comment: Anna esimerkki rajoitetusta funktiosta f : [0, 1] → R, jolla on primitiivi, mutta joka ei ole Riemann-integroituva. This is the question in Finnish.